# Doctrine 2 date comparison

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I came upon an interesting issue with doctrine while trying to get some values and I can't figure out why this is happening...

I have this:

```
$qb->from('Model_Match', 'm')
        ->leftJoin('m.betMatch', 'gbm')
        ->innerJoin('m.opponent1', 'opp1')
        ->innerJoin('m.opponent2', 'opp2')
        ->innerJoin('m.round', 'r')
        ->innerJoin('r.tournament', 't')
        ->innerJoin('t.game', 'g')
        ->select('m', 'partial gbm.{id}', 'opp1', 'opp2', 'r', 't', 'g')
        ->where('m.result IS NOT NULL')
        ->orderBy('m.dateTime', 'ASC');
```

This works like a charm, but as soon as I set a where comapring the m.dateTime field it exceeds the 30 secs execution time.

```
$qb->from('Model_Match', 'm')
        ->leftJoin('m.betMatch', 'gbm')
        ->innerJoin('m.opponent1', 'opp1')
        ->innerJoin('m.opponent2', 'opp2')
        ->innerJoin('m.round', 'r')
        ->innerJoin('r.tournament', 't')
        ->innerJoin('t.game', 'g')
        ->select('m', 'partial gbm.{id}', 'opp1', 'opp2', 'r', 't', 'g')
        ->where('m.result IS NOT NULL')
        ->orderBy('m.dateTime', 'ASC')
        ->andWhere('m.dateTime >= :date')
        ->setParameter("date", new \DateTime($fromDate));
```

Also, if i set the ->setMaxResults() to less than 3 it gets the data, if it's more than 2 it dies again.

Interestingly enough if I set the

```
->where('m.result IS NOT NULL')
```

to

```
->where('m.result IS NULL')
```

it fetches data...

Anyone has an idea why this may be happening?

Comment: try printing out the SQL and run the SQL itself, to make sure its not timing out waiting for the database to return results.

Comment: mysql returns the result within 0.14 seconds...

Comment: also, if i'm using prepared statements with the exact same query it returns the result instantly.